# Javascript - var not updating in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, validation, loops, for-loop

I'm building a simple trivia/quiz game in HTML and JAVASCRIPT, but i'm having problems validating the good responses, except the first one that validates well.

Javascript Code:

```
// global arrays
var index = 0;

var p = ['Quantos octetos tem um IPv4?',
  'Qual a mascara de 192.168.10.1/24?',
  'Qual o comando que verifica conexões de rede?',
];

var r = [
  ['4', '8', '16'],
  ['255.255.255.255', '255.255.255.0', '255.0.0.0', ],
  ['CHMOD', 'NETSTAT', 'PING']
];

function validar() {
  //if this is the last question hide and displays quiz ends            
  if (index >= p.length) {
    document.getElementById('per').innerHTML = '<div>earthTrivia End, Thank `you!</div>';
    document.getElementById('bt1').style.visibility = 'hidden ';
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById('score').innerText = score;
    document.getElementById('inp').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    estatistica(score);
    return false;
  }

  var html = '<div>' + p[index] + '</div>';
  for (var i = 0; i < r[index].length; i++) {
    html += '<label><h3>' + r[index][i] + '</label></h3>';

  }

  html += '</div > ';
  document.getElementById('per').innerHTML = html;

  index++;
  valrespostas();
}

function valrespostas() {
  var resposta = document.getElementById('inp').value;
  for (var j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
    var resposta = document.getElementById('inp').value;
    if (resposta[j] == r[0][0]) {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = '';
      document.getElementById('score').innerText = score++;
      break;
    } else if (resposta[j] == r[1][0]) {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = '';
      document.getElementById('score').innerText = score++;
      break;
    } else if (resposta[j] == r[2][0]) {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = '';
      document.getElementById('score').innerText = score++;
      break;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = '';
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('inp').value = '';
}
```

Every times my validar() function is called by a button in HTML file, its objective is to advance to the next question/answers in the global array's.
**This is working OK.**

Next the function valrespostas() is called and it must validate the answer the user inputs in a input form field.
This is NOT working. This only works for the first iteration of the for loop, in the remaining iterations the variable respostas holds the value of the first iteration and never changes to the new values and if the user chooses the correct answer it will NOT BE validated as good answer.

I read, here in STACK..., about loop closure, but could not find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using a array for your answers? It would be easier if it was a object with key/value

Comment: why do you have a loop in valrespostas? You only display one question, so there is only one answer to check at that moment. Also, you are performing the check when you have just displayed a new question. That seems to be the wrong order. You should not update the HTML elements that often. `index` should be used somewhere... etc, etc. Too many issues.

Comment: in the `valrespostas` function you are not using the index when you are getting values from your `r` array

Comment: Your remarks were very good. Solved almost every problems, but now it keeps saying when validates the last answer (if is the wrong answer) : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. In the followin line: for (var i = 0; i < r[index].length; i++).

Comment: It is now solved. Everything is OK. Your remarks made me see what was bad in the code.